# Splitting tensor into sub-tensors in overlapping fashion

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm in pytorch and I have a tensor `x` of size `batch_size x d x S`. It has to be intended as a batch of sequences of length `S`, where every sequence element is `d` dimensional. Every sequence is actually the overlap of multiple sub-sequences, in the following sense:

- every sub-sequence is of size `past_size + present_size`, i.e we have `past_size` `d`-dimensional elements followed by other `present_size` elements
- the overlap works as follows: the beginnings of the `present_size` sections are equispaced by `present_size` elements, and they are placed in the right-most positions

To make an example, with `batch_size=1, d=1`, consider `x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`, where `present_size = 2, past_size = 3`. The resulting subsequences would be:

1. `[1,2,3,4,5]`
2. `[3,4,5,6,7]`
3. `[5,6,7,8,9]`

The end goal is to produce the splitting of every sequence into the, say, `N` sub-sequences, to get a tensor of shape `batch_size*N x d x past_size+present_size`.

My **second** try is the following:

```
def seq(x, present_size, total_size=present_size+past_size, N):
   z = x.unfold(-1, total_size, present_size)
   v = torch.flatten(z, start_dim=2)
   s = torch.cat(torch.chunk(v, N, -1), 0)
   return s
```

### Is there a more efficient way? Is it possible to backpropagate through such a function?

**Edit**
In the above example, `N = 3`.

Moreover, we have the following relation: `N*present_size + past_size = S`

---

**Input-output**

Here is an example with `N=4, present_size = 1, past_size = 2`.

```
x = torch.rand(4,8,6) # d=8, batch_size = 4, 6 = N*present_size + past_size
>>> tensor([[[0.5667, 0.5300, 0.2460, 0.4327, 0.4727, 0.5649],
     [0.0360, 0.6687, 0.0167, 0.5359, 0.9804, 0.8778],
     [0.3703, 0.4884, 0.1505, 0.5463, 0.8114, 0.3270],
     [0.2932, 0.4928, 0.3933, 0.2433, 0.7053, 0.5222],
     [0.6667, 0.2014, 0.7107, 0.7535, 0.2816, 0.6515],
     [0.5285, 0.4150, 0.2557, 0.2144, 0.8317, 0.5448],
     [0.7971, 0.6609, 0.1811, 0.7788, 0.6649, 0.1848],
     [0.6902, 0.3999, 0.8719, 0.7624, 0.5216, 0.3494]],

    [[0.0196, 0.7850, 0.2796, 0.4173, 0.8076, 0.5709],
     [0.4566, 0.4814, 0.0568, 0.8568, 0.9119, 0.4030],
     [0.4031, 0.8887, 0.3782, 0.8015, 0.9835, 0.6043],
     [0.3557, 0.5960, 0.2102, 0.8165, 0.1938, 0.4948],
     [0.8163, 0.7907, 0.3711, 0.6835, 0.8021, 0.1897],
     [0.7790, 0.2621, 0.3769, 0.3830, 0.7140, 0.2309],
     [0.5831, 0.0246, 0.6548, 0.8694, 0.1988, 0.5470],
     [0.1192, 0.2928, 0.4240, 0.2624, 0.7959, 0.4091]],

    [[0.7959, 0.7144, 0.4523, 0.5090, 0.6053, 0.4071],
     [0.4742, 0.0224, 0.9939, 0.9757, 0.0732, 0.6213],
     [0.5211, 0.1149, 0.8218, 0.7061, 0.1807, 0.2822],
     [0.1456, 0.7331, 0.9107, 0.9533, 0.2438, 0.4031],
     [0.0958, 0.2623, 0.0828, 0.2861, 0.0474, 0.8349],
     [0.1740, 0.3658, 0.2416, 0.6735, 0.4013, 0.8896],
     [0.6934, 0.8709, 0.4017, 0.6121, 0.5824, 0.5803],
     [0.4811, 0.1036, 0.4356, 0.6441, 0.5859, 0.4683]],

    [[0.2479, 0.9247, 0.3216, 0.6844, 0.1701, 0.4609],
     [0.3320, 0.4908, 0.0458, 0.9887, 0.4725, 0.7511],
     [0.0594, 0.1978, 0.8830, 0.9126, 0.4821, 0.7731],
     [0.3729, 0.4921, 0.9266, 0.7827, 0.8101, 0.6258],
     [0.4998, 0.7596, 0.1160, 0.3928, 0.4773, 0.7892],
     [0.0215, 0.1325, 0.5940, 0.2094, 0.3109, 0.9281],
     [0.7960, 0.1707, 0.1793, 0.7335, 0.2065, 0.6204],
     [0.6350, 0.9696, 0.5099, 0.7375, 0.7601, 0.1405]]])


r = seq(x, 1, 2+1, 4)
>>> tensor([[[0.5667, 0.5300, 0.2460],
     [0.0360, 0.6687, 0.0167],
     [0.3703, 0.4884, 0.1505],
     [0.2932, 0.4928, 0.3933],
     [0.6667, 0.2014, 0.7107],
     [0.5285, 0.4150, 0.2557],
     [0.7971, 0.6609, 0.1811],
     [0.6902, 0.3999, 0.8719]],

    [[0.0196, 0.7850, 0.2796],
     [0.4566, 0.4814, 0.0568],
     [0.4031, 0.8887, 0.3782],
     [0.3557, 0.5960, 0.2102],
     [0.8163, 0.7907, 0.3711],
     [0.7790, 0.2621, 0.3769],
     [0.5831, 0.0246, 0.6548],
     [0.1192, 0.2928, 0.4240]],

    [[0.7959, 0.7144, 0.4523],
     [0.4742, 0.0224, 0.9939],
     [0.5211, 0.1149, 0.8218],
     [0.1456, 0.7331, 0.9107],
     [0.0958, 0.2623, 0.0828],
     [0.1740, 0.3658, 0.2416],
     [0.6934, 0.8709, 0.4017],
     [0.4811, 0.1036, 0.4356]],

    [[0.2479, 0.9247, 0.3216],
     [0.3320, 0.4908, 0.0458],
     [0.0594, 0.1978, 0.8830],
     [0.3729, 0.4921, 0.9266],
     [0.4998, 0.7596, 0.1160],
     [0.0215, 0.1325, 0.5940],
     [0.7960, 0.1707, 0.1793],
     [0.6350, 0.9696, 0.5099]],

    [[0.5300, 0.2460, 0.4327],
     [0.6687, 0.0167, 0.5359],
     [0.4884, 0.1505, 0.5463],
     [0.4928, 0.3933, 0.2433],
     [0.2014, 0.7107, 0.7535],
     [0.4150, 0.2557, 0.2144],
     [0.6609, 0.1811, 0.7788],
     [0.3999, 0.8719, 0.7624]],

    [[0.7850, 0.2796, 0.4173],
     [0.4814, 0.0568, 0.8568],
     [0.8887, 0.3782, 0.8015],
     [0.5960, 0.2102, 0.8165],
     [0.7907, 0.3711, 0.6835],
     [0.2621, 0.3769, 0.3830],
     [0.0246, 0.6548, 0.8694],
     [0.2928, 0.4240, 0.2624]],

    [[0.7144, 0.4523, 0.5090],
     [0.0224, 0.9939, 0.9757],
     [0.1149, 0.8218, 0.7061],
     [0.7331, 0.9107, 0.9533],
     [0.2623, 0.0828, 0.2861],
     [0.3658, 0.2416, 0.6735],
     [0.8709, 0.4017, 0.6121],
     [0.1036, 0.4356, 0.6441]],

    [[0.9247, 0.3216, 0.6844],
     [0.4908, 0.0458, 0.9887],
     [0.1978, 0.8830, 0.9126],
     [0.4921, 0.9266, 0.7827],
     [0.7596, 0.1160, 0.3928],
     [0.1325, 0.5940, 0.2094],
     [0.1707, 0.1793, 0.7335],
     [0.9696, 0.5099, 0.7375]],

    [[0.2460, 0.4327, 0.4727],
     [0.0167, 0.5359, 0.9804],
     [0.1505, 0.5463, 0.8114],
     [0.3933, 0.2433, 0.7053],
     [0.7107, 0.7535, 0.2816],
     [0.2557, 0.2144, 0.8317],
     [0.1811, 0.7788, 0.6649],
     [0.8719, 0.7624, 0.5216]],

    [[0.2796, 0.4173, 0.8076],
     [0.0568, 0.8568, 0.9119],
     [0.3782, 0.8015, 0.9835],
     [0.2102, 0.8165, 0.1938],
     [0.3711, 0.6835, 0.8021],
     [0.3769, 0.3830, 0.7140],
     [0.6548, 0.8694, 0.1988],
     [0.4240, 0.2624, 0.7959]],

    [[0.4523, 0.5090, 0.6053],
     [0.9939, 0.9757, 0.0732],
     [0.8218, 0.7061, 0.1807],
     [0.9107, 0.9533, 0.2438],
     [0.0828, 0.2861, 0.0474],
     [0.2416, 0.6735, 0.4013],
     [0.4017, 0.6121, 0.5824],
     [0.4356, 0.6441, 0.5859]],

    [[0.3216, 0.6844, 0.1701],
     [0.0458, 0.9887, 0.4725],
     [0.8830, 0.9126, 0.4821],
     [0.9266, 0.7827, 0.8101],
     [0.1160, 0.3928, 0.4773],
     [0.5940, 0.2094, 0.3109],
     [0.1793, 0.7335, 0.2065],
     [0.5099, 0.7375, 0.7601]],

    [[0.4327, 0.4727, 0.5649],
     [0.5359, 0.9804, 0.8778],
     [0.5463, 0.8114, 0.3270],
     [0.2433, 0.7053, 0.5222],
     [0.7535, 0.2816, 0.6515],
     [0.2144, 0.8317, 0.5448],
     [0.7788, 0.6649, 0.1848],
     [0.7624, 0.5216, 0.3494]],

    [[0.4173, 0.8076, 0.5709],
     [0.8568, 0.9119, 0.4030],
     [0.8015, 0.9835, 0.6043],
     [0.8165, 0.1938, 0.4948],
     [0.6835, 0.8021, 0.1897],
     [0.3830, 0.7140, 0.2309],
     [0.8694, 0.1988, 0.5470],
     [0.2624, 0.7959, 0.4091]],

    [[0.5090, 0.6053, 0.4071],
     [0.9757, 0.0732, 0.6213],
     [0.7061, 0.1807, 0.2822],
     [0.9533, 0.2438, 0.4031],
     [0.2861, 0.0474, 0.8349],
     [0.6735, 0.4013, 0.8896],
     [0.6121, 0.5824, 0.5803],
     [0.6441, 0.5859, 0.4683]],

    [[0.6844, 0.1701, 0.4609],
     [0.9887, 0.4725, 0.7511],
     [0.9126, 0.4821, 0.7731],
     [0.7827, 0.8101, 0.6258],
     [0.3928, 0.4773, 0.7892],
     [0.2094, 0.3109, 0.9281],
     [0.7335, 0.2065, 0.6204],
     [0.7375, 0.7601, 0.1405]]])
```

Comment: What is `N` in your example? Your current implementation doesn't work, please fix it or provide a full example: this includes the inputs and the desired outputs.

Comment: @Ivan I've written what N is, specified the outputs a bit more, and also have fixed my example. I removed the intital zero, I can assume that there are no "remainders" in my application

Comment: Could you provide an additional (with different inputs) example?

Comment: @Ivan Here it is

Comment: @Ivan I've created a second version of the script, my first version was over complicated

Answer (score 1):

#### Possible method using `torch.gather`

You can see this problem as reassigning each element to a new position. This has to be done using a tensor containing the indices of the permutation you which to see happening.

If you look at the indices of the last dimension for input `x` (we will take your example with `x.shape = (4, 8, 6)`), you have them ordered this way:

```
tensor([[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
         [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
          ... 4 more
         [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
         [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]],
        
        ... 2 more

        [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
         [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
          ... 4 more
         [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
         [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]])
```

Now the permutation of indices should be looking like (considering `N=4`, `present_size=1`, and `past_size=2`). Keep in mind I'm only representing two dimensions among the four `x` in total:

```
tensor([[0, 1, 2],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [2, 3, 4],
        [3, 4, 5]])
```

From there it will be easy to construct the new tensor using [`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.gather.html). The operation will effectively create a tensor `out` defined in the following way:

```
out[i][j][k][l] = x[i][j][k][indices[i, j, k, l]]
```

---

#### 1. Constructing the tensor of indices

In order to construct such tensor of indices, we will use arrangements. The following are the base indices:

```
>>> arr = torch.arange(total_size)[None].repeat(N, 1)
tensor([[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2]])
```

to which we add a displacement of `present_size` accumulated over the rows:

```
>>> disp = torch.arange(0, total_size + 1, step=present_size)[None].T
tensor([[0],
        [1],
        [2],
        [3]])
```

The resulting *minimal* tensor of indices is:

```
>>> indices = arr + disp
tensor([[0, 1, 2],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [2, 3, 4],
        [3, 4, 5]])
```

---

#### 2. Applying `torch.gather`

First, we need to expand the rows of `x` to `N`: the number of rows in the resulting tensor.

```
>>> x_r = x[None].expand(N, *(-1,)*x.ndim)
>>> x.shape, x_r.shape
(torch.Size([4, 8, 6]), torch.Size([4, 4, 8, 6]))
```

In order to use `torch.gather`, we need the input and tensor of indices to have the same shape. To do so we can make views of our tensors using [`Tensor.expand`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.expand.html).

So here we will insert two additional dimensions on `indices` and expand them to match the sizes of `x`'s first and second axis.

```
>>> i_r = indices[:, None, None, :].expand(-1, x.size(0), x.size(1), -1)
indices.shape, i_r.shape
(torch.Size([4, 3]), torch.Size([4, 4, 8, 3]))
```

Then apply the gather function on the last axis of indices:

```
>>> torch.gather(x_r, dim=-1, index=i_r)
tensor([[[[0.5667, 0.5300, 0.2460],
          [0.0360, 0.6687, 0.0167],
          [0.3703, 0.4884, 0.1505],
          [0.2932, 0.4928, 0.3933],
          [0.6667, 0.2014, 0.7107],
          [0.5285, 0.4150, 0.2557],
          [0.7971, 0.6609, 0.1811],
          [0.6902, 0.3999, 0.8719]],

         ...
           
        [[0.6844, 0.1701, 0.4609],
         [0.9887, 0.4725, 0.7511],
         [0.9126, 0.4821, 0.7731],
         [0.7827, 0.8101, 0.6258],
         [0.3928, 0.4773, 0.7892],
         [0.2094, 0.3109, 0.9281],
         [0.7335, 0.2065, 0.6204],
         [0.7375, 0.7601, 0.1405]]]])
```

*If you have any questions, please don't hesitate to ask!*